# check if array contains all array values from another array in C

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, contains

I tried to make a program that will check if an an array contains all the array values from another array. So, if that's true, the program will return 1 using a value for it. If it isn't true, it will return 0(I named it p). I failed to make that program though. Could you please help me?

Comment: Hint: If both arrays were sorted, how could you test easily whether one contains the other?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isSubset(int arr1[], int arr2[], int m, int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<m; j++)
        {
           if(arr2[i] == arr1[j])
              break;
        }

        /* If the above inner loop was not broken at all then
           arr2[i] is not present in arr1[] */
        if (j == m)
           return 0;
    }

    /* If we reach here then all elements of arr2[] 
      are present in arr1[] */
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int arr1[] = {11, 1, 13, 21, 3, 7};
    int arr2[] = {11, 2, 7, 1};

    int m = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]);
    int n = sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(arr2[0]);

    if(isSubset(arr1, arr2, m, n))
      printf("arr2[] is subset of arr1[] ");
    else
      printf("arr2[] is not a subset of arr1[]");      

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**Ideone Link up and running** : http://ideone.com/4u9oQm

Comment: Time Complexity: O(m*n)