# Comparing two arrays in C ignoring the order of the elements inside each array

Tags: arrays, c, random, comparison, nested-loops

I want to compare two arrays in C, ignoring the order of the elements inside each array, I had two ideas to solve this problem.
Well, they're the same, to be honest. The first idea is to make a variable and increment it with 1 if we find our element inside the second table (please see the code below).
But this one doesn't work if we give it as an example `{3, 2, 2, 1} {1, 2, 3, 4}`.
the second idea (which I obviously couldn't code) is: setting a variable `c=0` for example, after the first loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    c = 0;
    for (...
}
```

this `c` will count the number of fails

```
if (T1[i] != T2[j]) {
    c += 1
}
```

Then before exiting the `j` loop, we check if `c==n` where n is the length of the table. Meaning we have n fails.
after that, unsetting `c`at the beginning of the `i` loop

this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, i, j, c = 0;
    printf("give the size of the first array: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int T1[n];
    int T2[n];
    // remplissage de T1
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("give the value of %d case, table1: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &T1[i]);
    }
    // remplissage de T2
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("give the value of %d case, table2: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &T2[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (T1[i] == T2[j]) {
                c += 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (c == n) {
        printf("True");
    } else {
        printf("False");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [check if array contains all array values from another array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821519/check-if-array-contains-all-array-values-from-another-array-in-c)

Comment: I would sort the arrays, then compare.  Barring that, I would create a bit vector of the same size as the arrays, then use it to check off values from the first array that I'd found in the second array.

Comment: You need 3rd array (T3) with flags which element is already found equal (reserved). Loop on T1, compare with all elements of T2 and set flag if value is found. On next iteration the element of T2 which is "true" in T3 array will be skipped. `if ( T1[i] == T2[j] && T3[j] == 0 ) { T3[j] = 1; c++; }`

Comment: @sagi thank you for responding, no try switching the values of the arrays that I gave above, the thing is that I don't want only to check if the elements of the first array are present in the second one, but compare them { meaning if arra1 == arra2 } ignoring the order.

Comment: This is a classical exercise. There's the naïve O(n*n) solution and the proper O(n log n) solution. With 4 elements, it doesn't matter. With 4 million elements, only the latter is practical.

Comment: It would be wise to test all solutions against a bunch of test cases, such as `{1,1,2} != {1,2,2}`. Yes, both arrays contain the same values, and the count method would find 3 matches each way, but the arrays are obviously not the same.

Comment: @MSalters, yeah, that's the question. As Steve said, it's better to sort the arrays first before comparing them, but sometimes it's not allowed.

Comment: @oussama101: In that case, you'd copy the arrays and sort the copies. That's just O(n) extra. In general, if you add extra constraints, be precise what those constraints are. It's quite possible for a single problem to have a dozen different optimal solutions, just optimal for different constraints.

Answer (score 0):

With this approach

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (T1[i] == T2[j]) {
            c += 1;
            break;
            }
        }
    }
```

the two arrays `int T1[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };` and `int T2[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };` will be always equal.

Also the approach with two pairs of such nested for loops where the arrays are swapped in the if statement will not help. In this case for example these arrays `int T1[] = { 1, 2, 2, 2 };` and `int T2[] = { 1, 1, 1, 2 };` again will be equal.

If you are allowed to sort arrays then you should sort the both arrays and compare them.

Otherwise you can use the approach shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { n = 5 };

    int a1[n] = { 1, 2, 3, 2, 1 };
    int a2[n] = { 3, 2, 2, 1, 1 };

    int equal = 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; equal && i < n; i++)
    {
        size_t count = 1;
        for (size_t j = 0; j != i; j++)
        {
            if (a1[i] == a1[j]) ++count;
        }

        for (size_t j = 0; count && j < n; j++)
        {
            if (a2[j] == a1[i]) --count;
        }

        equal = count == 0;
    }

    printf( "The arrays are %sequal.\n", equal ? "" : "not " );
}
```

The program output is

```
The arrays are equal.
```

Comment: `if (a1[i] == a1[j]) ++count;` - that's counting duplicates in `a1`? Makes sense. If you're looking for 1 in `a2`, you should look for two occurrences. But it only counts duplicates up to position `i`. As a result, you need that `count!=0` check in the next loop, and it's not exactly efficient.

Comment: @MSalters In my opinion your comment does not make a sense. The task of the beginner is to use nested for loops to determine whether two unsorted arrays  contain the same elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think i've found what you are asking for.
You need to do two double for to check equality in both ways, and then compare those 2 numbers.

```
    int c = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++){
            if(A1[i] == A2[y]){
                c += 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    int d = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++){
            if(A2[i] == A1[y]){
                d += 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if(c != n || d != n || c != d){
        printf("False");
    }else{
        printf("true");
    }
```

If **c** and **d** are not the same it means that there is a duplicate that triggers 2 times the equal in one way.
If **c** and **d** are the same but not equal to the array size it means that there are no duplicates, but not all the elements of one array are in the other.

I hope i've been helpfull

Comment: Have you tested this with {1,1,2} and {1,2,2} ? It looks like `c==d==n==3` in that case

Answer (score 0):

Your approach fails if there are duplicates in the first array: `{ 0, 0 }` will compare equal to `{ 0, 1 }`. If you were to compare `T1` and `T2` both ways, you would still have this counter example: `{ 0, 0, 1 }` and `{ 0, 1, 1 }`.

You can work around this problem by counting the number of occurrences in both arrays of each element in one of the arrays: the arrays contain the same numbers if all counts match:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count(int val, const int *T, int n) {
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        c += (T[i] == val);
    return c;
}

int main() {
    int n, i;
    printf("give the size of the first array: \n");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        return 1;
    int T1[n];
    int T2[n];
    // remplissage de T1
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("give the value of %d case, table1: ", i + 1);
        if (scanf("%d", &T1[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    // remplissage de T2
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("give the value of %d case, table2: ", i + 1);
        if (scanf("%d", &T2[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (count(T1[i], T1, n) != count(T1[i], T2, n))
            break;
    }
    if (i == n) {
        printf("True\n");
    } else {
        printf("False\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code has a time complexity of **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** because of the nested loops. You pay get better performance for large `n` by sorting both arrays and comparing them sequentially (complexity **O(n.log(n))**.)